# 502 nginx bad gateway, but only when not printing the array

Tags: php, nginx, server

I have a php based website with a big amount of data stored in .json files. In order to search certain data, I have implemented a search/ filter function, with which I can filter for the date of creation, name, etc. the server gets the filter variables when the user submits the post-form.

When receiving the post-request the server stores the post-variables in a session for another purpose and then goes through the main table-of-content.json file and checks for which element more data from other files is needed.

But when I do one specific filter setting I get a **502 nginx bad gateway error**. The error just occurs when I select the whole month of June and 'every type', but when I select the entire timespan, a different month or I filter for just one half of the month (either the first or second half) the problem does not occur. Furthermore, when I print the array of filtered data with `print_r()` the problem doesn't occur either.

Can someone please help me I have no idea why this is happening?!

Comment: Please share the code you are using

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?